# Laravel json convert to array only number PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have code:

```
return $getId = Permission::select('id')->get();
```

This code returned me:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]
```

**I want to query returned the records in the form of:**

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

How can I do this? I tried to use `json_decode`, but it's not work I also tried to use a foreach loop, but the result was the same. I'm doing this because I want to compare the two tables using `array_diff`, but still I have error:

> array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array

`Argument 1` is variable `$getId`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `pluck()` and `toArray()` methods:

```
return $getId = Permission::pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: your answer is better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the result in **Collection** and use **pluck** method:

```
$permissions = Permission::select('id')->get();
$ids = collect($permissions)->pluck('id')->all(); // all() to array
```

More on Laravel collections pluck [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck)